# create thumbnails from big movies with FFmpeg takes too long

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this shell command to make thumbnail from VIDEO_FILE from 123 second and save it to THUMBNAIL_FILE.

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO_FILE  -r 1 -ss 123 -f image2 THUMBNAIL_FILE
```

It works, but it is really slow for big movies.  Is there any way to make it a little faster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it has happened to me also, changing the argument order fixes this problem.
tested on a 1.4GB 90 minute mp4 video - took about 1-2 seconds. before that it took MINUTES...

try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 123 -i "VIDEO_FILE" "THUMBNAIL_FILE" -r 1 -vframes 1 -an -vcodec mjpeg
```

Comment: Testing on a 4GB MKV file I got: 1.23s on using `mplayer` and 1.687s using the above `ffmpeg` command. Both were taken from the third second of the video and are identical in resolution and size.

Comment: Note that this way is not as reliable as the "slow way" - it can sometimes grab the wrong frame (which may or may not be important of course) and sometimes grabs a "p-frame or b-frame" - a frame that doesn't contain enough information to recreate the full image - in short, it could be all grey or blocky.

Comment: @DarrenGreaves - the caveat doesn't apply for the given command, at least not anymore. When transcoding, ffmpeg will internally decode from the prior keyframe.

Comment: How do i fix this in my nodejs code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202448/taking-too-long-to-generate-a-screenshot-in-ffmpeg

Comment: How can i do this in c#?

Answer (score 4):

Ffmpeg is not really good with creating thumbnails as I investigated. People recommend to use mplayer (by ffmpeg creators).

```
mplayer VIDEO_FILE -ss 00:10:11 -frames 1 -vo jpeg:outdir=THUMBNAILS_DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

A small enhancement to Kirzilla's code: If you want to create PNG files (with compression), you can use the following code:

```
mplayer VIDEO_FILE -ss 00:10:11 -frames 1 -vo png:z=9:outdir=THUMBNAILS_DIRECTORY
```

This will probably create better thumbnails but of course with a larger size than JPEG.